# Is $f(x) = -1.5$ a negligible function?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, one-way-function, negligible

Is $f(x) = -1.5$ a negligible function? Since it satisfies the condition for a negligible function?

Comment: Since a non negligible function can take a minimum value of 0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics in general. But if you look at your definition of negligible functions, it probably says to take the absolute value.

Comment: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sanjamg/classes/cs276-fall14/scribe/lec02.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You could probably have answered your own question with a quick look at the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function): a function $\mu(\cdot)$ is negligible if for every positive $c$, there is an integer $N_c$ such that for all integers $x > N_c$, $|\mu(x)| < 1/x^c$. The function $f : x \mapsto -1.5$ is clearly non-negligible according to this definition.

Moreover, even without looking at the exact definition, if you think of the (cryptographic) purpose of a negligible function (bounding the probability that an adversary does something he should not be able to do), it would have made no sense to define it so that any negative function is negligible. One can therefore guess that cryptographers try to use definitions that make sense :)

Comment: According to the definition itself $-2^{-n}$ is negligible

Comment: Sure, but $2^{-n}$ is not "any negative function" it clearly satisfies the intuitive "goes very quickly to zero" requirement.

Comment: The definition I was looking at didn't mention about the "absolute value". I think they took it for granted, which made all the confusion for me. Thanks.
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sanjamg/classes/cs276-fall14/scribe/lec02.pdf

Comment: I see. Slides are usually not meant to be fully formal anyway, they they are à support for some oral course. In case of hesitation, it's better to first look at the formal définition

Comment: That Wikipedia article is very poorly sourced, I wouldn't use it as a reference.